# (Render Error) Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components)or a class/function(for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

i am trying to learn react native but i faced with this error:

**Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components)or a class/function(for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in or you might hace mixed up default and named imports.**

**Check the render method of 'GoalInput'**(I am sure i didn't made a typo first'l' and after that 'i' letter)

***my App.js code:***

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Button } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import GoalItem from "./components/GoalItem";
import GoalInput from "./components/GoalInput";

return (
    <>
      <StatusBar/>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={startAddGoalHandler}/>
        <GoalInput
          visible={modalIsVisible}
          onAddGoal={addGoalHandler}
          onCancel={endAddGoalHandler}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

***my GoalInput.js code:***

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet,Button,TextInput,View,Model,Image} from "react-native";

const GoalInput = (props) => {
  const [enteredGoalText, setEnteredGoalText] = useState("");

  const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
    setEnteredGoalText(enteredText);
  };

  const addGoalHandler = () => {
    props.onAddGoal(enteredGoalText);   
    setEnteredGoalText("");
  };

  return (
    <Model visible={props.visible} animationType="slide">
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/Images/goal.png")}
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
          value={enteredGoalText}
        />
        <View>
          <View>
            <Button title="Add Goal" onPress={addGoalHandler} color="#b180f0" />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Button title="Cancel" onPress={props.onCancel} color="#f31282" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Model>
  );
};

export default GoalInput;
```

I have deleted the style parts for keep question simple and even i search a lot couldn't find the error source on my own thanks for all the attention.

by the way i am using 'expo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `Model` in react native , its `Modal`

SO chnage this first :

```
import { StyleSheet,Button,TextInput,View,Modal,Image} from "react-native";
```

And also where youve used in

```
return(
<Modal>
</Modal>
)
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts